# Clickable tableofcontents

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

How to obtain clickable items in a table of contents? I mean, they should also appear in blue. 
I have the preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{iopart}

\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\usepackage{iopams}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

As you can see, I'm using the `iopart` class (specific for IOP journals).

Comment: Did you run `pdflatex` twice? The first time it is run an .aux file is read upon a subsequent run.

Comment: Yes, sure, more than twice! After the abstract I simply put \tableofcontents, should I say something else?

Comment: Ok, then it would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @martina: no problems at all. I'll close it as a duplicate of the answers you pointed if your problem is fixed.

Comment: So, just curious what exactly solved your issue. You are already including `hyperref`.

Comment: Yes, but I wasn't setting it up. I simply added: \hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linktoc=all,  
    linkcolor=blue,
}

Comment: @martina: I am pretty sure that the defaults should have produced click able links up on a second compile (without deleting the `.aux` files).

Comment: I don't really know. I'll probably have to try on another machine to check.

Comment: Indeed, it works on other machines.